# Can't retrieve data through sqldatareader

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqldatareader

I want to retrieve data from sql database and set that data to some textboxes based on the value I'm providing. Like, if I'm providing a name "John" it should fetch all the data against john and put that on the textboxes. Code is as follow

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM PatientInfo WHERE Name LIKE '@Name';";
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
   {
       cn.Open();
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",String.Format("%{0}%", txtsearchpatient.Text));
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtid_search.Text = reader["PatientID"].ToString();
                txtname_search.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                txtphone_search.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
                txtage_search.Text = reader["Age"].ToString();
                txtaddress_search.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
                txtemail_search.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
            }
         }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record found");
        }
        reader.Close();
        cn.Close();
   }
```

I am getting error "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" while when I'm manually executing query in sql management studio with the same query it is returning all the fields successfully. Where is the problem?

Comment: `LIKE '@Name'` should be `LIKE @Name`

Comment: It worked :O  When I was doing this it was saying "must declare scalar variable Name" but now it worked. Thanks alot . Please post your response so that I can mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your SQL string you used `'@Name'` which is scalar string value `"@Name"` rather the intended `@Name` parameter.

Simply remove the enclosing single quotation marks around the `@Name` and the problem will be solved.